# How to use 'forceCommunity:searchInterface' in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community-builder

I have a requirement where I need to use custom search LWC in community search component. I was able to achieve using Aura but I could not find option in LWC. Is it supported in LWC ?

Need help.

Thanks,
Ashvin

Answer (score 1):

As of Winter'21 release forceCommunity:searchInterface is not available in LWC

If you see the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceCommunity:searchInterface/documentation) the View as Lightning Web Component is greyed out.

[image]

Though Lightning web components support most of the functionality available in Aura components, there are few exceptions and forceCommunity:searchInterface is one of those.

The [blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/02/working-with-aura-and-lightning-web-components-interoperability-and-migration.html) provides the complete list of unsupported LWCs.

EDIT: As suggested by  Phil, LWC can be wrapped in a simple Aura component implementing this interface. See [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.interop_aura_composition) .This way, most of the functionality can still be achieved using LWC.

Comment: Please update the answer to indicate that an LWC can be wrapped in a simple Aura component implementing this interface so most of the functionality can still be LWC-based. Then I'll upvote it.

Comment: Thank you, Phil :)  I have mentioned the same and provided an example in the edited comment.